# Buttons in lightning experience

Tags: lightning, custom-button

I'm using Lightning Experience. I have 2 objects, A and B. B has a lookup to A.

I need to create a new record on B when user clicks a button on A. I have created the button on A, but I can't figure how to pass values to autopopulate and link automatically the new record (B) with A.

Comment: This is one of the limitation of lightning.
you would have to write code in trigger and on UI fill only information required for object B

Answer (score 0):

I propose use process bulder to update/create object B and autopopulate field from Object A. 
And select The process starts when record change. Every time when you change Object A process builder automatic update on object B.

In this solution you don't need use button.

Comment: This could be a solution but I need to fill some fields manually when creating the record in the object B.

Comment: So are you saying you would want it to flow like this? Click a button on A, user is prompted to fill in some additional fields that would be populated on B, then record B is created that is related to A (containing some data from A and some data that was entered after clicking the button)?

Comment: Yes Lisa, optionally if possibile the user should see which fields are autopopulated after clicking button on A, and if necessary modify one or more before saving the new record.